# ElasticSearch nested objects - get unique fields with their respective values

Tags: elasticsearch

We're a bit confused by how to store the following data to retrieve it later with ease. We will have a million records, of the following form:

```
{ 
  "width" : 720
  "height" : 200
  "coords" : [{
               "el" : "xyz",
               "x-y" : "100-50"
              },
              {
               "el" : "abc",
               "x-y" : "200-150"
              }]
},
{ 
  "width" : 1280
  "height" : 1000
  "coords" : [{
               "el" : "lmn",
               "x-y" : "400-50"
              },
              {
               "el" : "abc",
               "x-y" : "500-250"
              }]
}
```

What type of aggregation query will we need to run to get the data in the following form? As of now, I could only search for queries which return unique values with their respective count (i.e., number of occurances).

```
{
 "el" : "xyz",
 "x-y" : ["100-50"]
},
{
 "el" : "abc",
 "x-y" : ["200-150","500-250"]
},
{
 "el" : "lmn",
 "x-y" : ["400-50"]
}
```

We have created a mapping, where "coords" is of type `nested`.
We can still change the mapping to get better performance and results as we are still in development phase.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to flatten you el's and x-y's if you have big data and need aggregation of a nested object like coords. You can add an aggregation string to your mapping;

```
{ 
  "width" : 1280
  "height" : 1000
  "coords" : [{
               "el" : "lmn",
               "x-y" : "400-50"
              },
              {
               "el" : "abc",
               "x-y" : "500-250"
              }]
  "coords-foraggregation" : "lmn,400-500;abc,500-200;nnn,xxx..."
}
```

**And you can add analyzer for "coords-foraggregation" field in your mapping model**.(https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) This way could be faster than aggregate both coords.el and coords.x-y ...

Comment: what we want is : unique "el" with all the "x-y" values corresponding to each "el". Where as Analyzer indexes each word separately. How will we able to achieve the result we want?

Comment: you can achieve that with custom analyzer which splits strings by specified char.